# Debian wheezy keyboard shortcut for both opening and closing a terminal

Tags: linux, bash, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, debian

I recently installed tilda and I would like to open it and close with the same keyboard shortcut. I wrote little something in bash that closes tilda if it is open and opens tilda when there is no such a process in ps -ef. It looks like this:

a=`ps -ef | fgrep -i tilda | cut -d' ' -f4 | head -1`;if [ $a ] ; then kill $a; else tilda; fi

It seems to be working (at least partially) when I commit this in terminal, but when I assign this command to specific keyboard shortcut (for example alt+1) it does nothing. Any suggestions?

btw. is it possible to assign this shortcut for button '`' like in Quake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use

```
bash -c "a=`ps -ef | fgrep -i tilda | cut -d' ' -f4 | head -1`;if [ $a ] ; then kill $a; else tilda; fi"
```

as  the field is expected to be a single program name or path and arguments, and not a shell script. Or you can place that script in a file and give it a `#!/bin/bash` and `chmod +x` it and give the path to that script instead.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you killing Tilda instead of hiding it? I use Tilda and have assigned a keyboard shortcut to show/hide it. Tilda starts upon login. Check Tilda's preferences.

Comment: I didn't know that ... That helped me too :) Thanks!